# Simple Recursive Javascript Function Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

For an assignment I am supposed to write a recursive function that checks any integer for even or odd using N-2. If even returns true else returns false. But it returns undefined whenever a value is large enough to call itself. Please help!

```
function isEven(num) {
  console.log("top of function num = " + num);// For Debugging
  if (num == 0){
      return true;
  }
  else if (num == 1){
      return false;
  }
  else {
    num -= 2;
    console.log("num = " + num);
    isEven(num);
  }
}
console.log(isEven(0));
// → true
console.log(isEven(1));
// → false
console.log(isEven(8));
// → ??
```

Console Log Results:

```
top of function num = 0

true

top of function num = 1

false

top of function num = 8

num = 6

top of function num = 6

num = 4

top of function num = 4

num = 2

top of function num = 2

num = 0

top of function num = 0

undefined
```

Comment: Your `else` case in `isEven` never returns a value.

Comment: The else really does need to return a value!

Comment: Great, homework teaching you the wrong ways to use a recursive function. Use modulus instead.

Comment: @Xorifelse The point is to become comfortable writing recursive functions, not to write an efficient test of whether a number is even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten the `return` statement before the recursive `isEven(num)` call.

See the snippet below:

```js
function isEven(num) {
  //console.log("top of function num = " + num);// For Debugging
  if (num == 0){
      return true;
  }
  else if (num == 1){
      return false;
  }
  else {
    num -= 2;
    return isEven(num);
  }
}
console.log('0 is even: ', isEven(0));
// → true
console.log('1 is even: ', isEven(1));
// → false
console.log('8 is even: ', isEven(8));
```

Comment: Oh, @cyber_rookie seems to have beaten me to it. Really unsure why we both got -1'd though, our answer is most certainly correct!

Comment: Excellent! Would you be so kind to mark the answer as the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder and once again thank you so much for the fix.

Comment: Use the snippet button in the button bar when typing an answer :) (Ctrl+M also seems to do it on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following line:

```
isEven(num);
```

to

```
return isEven(num);
```